# How to forward "http headers" from one host to another host in jsp or servlets?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, http-headers

I am Setting the headers  in my jsp

the code of my jsp is:

```
response.setHeader("msisdn", "919999988888888");
response.sendRedirect("http://someIp/projects2/getsetHeader_al.jsp");
```

and in another  server  i am not able to  get the  header that i have set in my previous jsp:

```
     java.util.Enumeration e = request.getHeaderNames();

        String msisdn="";
         while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
                String key = (String) e.nextElement();
                key = key.trim();


 if ((key.indexOf("msisdn") > -1) || (key.indexOf("MSISDN") > -1)) {
                  msisdn =   request.getHeader(key);
                        out.println("msisdn is "+msisdn);

                }

}
```

I am redirecting the response from one host to  another is there any
way  to send headers and headers value with redirecting url ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not possible.

A redirect is actually a response back to the original requestor with a 3xx response code that tells the requestor to try again with a different URL.  When you set a custom header in the response, it goes to the original requestor.  Unless the requestor is an application that:

- is handling any redirections "by hand", AND
- knows what to do with your header should be copied into the request when it sends it,

your header will not get passed on.

I suggest that you try passing that information as part of the redirect URL.

---

> Due to security reasons i cant include these value in the url.

If your concern is the user's security, then the solution is simple.  Use HTTPS throughout.  That will stop third-parties from seeing the redirected request URL.

If your concern is protecting your application from your user, then don't use redirection.  Anything in the response that goes back to the user is accessible to the user ... if he / she wants to look.

> Is there any othere way to send information from one host to another host secretly when forwarding response to another webserver.

You could encrypt it.  However, beware of "replay" attacks.

Comment: Due to security reasons i cant include these value in th url ... what i want to do is  ..... i will get yhe headers from the user and then modify the headers and after i want to send these modified headers with the redirecting url without showing on the browser's url

Comment: Is there any othere way to send information from one host to another host secreatly when forwarding response to another webserver